# How to fill a CGPathRef overlap like this?

Tags: ios, cgpath

I want to draw a single path, which can overlap itself. What I want is like a snap of Moves below:

[image]

Can I achieve this just fill a single CGPathRef on iOS?

I created two paths, a gray one and red one below:

[image]

There are two overlaps on the gray line, one for itself and one for the red line. The red overlap, you can see it clearly, is above (or below) the gray one. But the gray overlap is just merged.

The Moves trace line is a single line, maybe is not implemented by a single path fill or stroke.

Here's my code:

```
[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3] setStroke];

CGFloat lineWidth = 10.0;

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
path.lineWidth = lineWidth;

[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 50)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20, 400)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 400)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(20, 50)];
[path stroke];

[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:0.5] setStroke];
UIBezierPath *anotherPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
anotherPath.lineWidth = lineWidth;

[anotherPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(160, 50)];
[anotherPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 200)];
[anotherPath stroke];
```

Comment: what makes you to think that is _one_ single curve?

Comment: I don't, I just want to find a way to do it.